# Sequlize .authenticate? err

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can not find a solution why, I can not connect to the database, please tell me where my mistake
I try to output whether the database is connected or not, but I get an error
index:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const { sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const { connection } = require('connection');

sequelize 
.authenticate()
.then(function(err) {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

connection:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const fs = require("fs");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");



module.exports = connection = {
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: process.env.HOST_DB,
  dialect: "mysql",
  timezone: "+03:00",
  dialectOptions: {
    charset: "utf8mb4",
  },
  logging: false
};

  
  

module.exports = {
    development: connection
  };
```

error:

```
.authenticate()
 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authenticate')
```

Comment: I guess Sequalize is missing the connection parameters: `sequelize = new Sequelize(connection);` and then authenticate

Comment: @tttony, no
sequelize = new Sequelize(connection)
^

ReferenceError: Sequelize is not defined